# Replacing middle & last names in many Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, editing, wildcards

I have about 200 letters I need to be sending out through email to people, and right now the header is set up like this:

`Dear FirstName MiddleName LastName,`

But my boss would like it to just be set up like this:

`Dear FirstName,`

I have already put in these 200+ names, so going back through and removing all middle and last names would take a bit of time. I have a program that will find and replace text in all 200 Word documents by itself, but I have to tell the program what to search for and what to replace it with.

So, is there any way I can do a find and replace in Word that would change, for example, these greetings

- `Dear Bob Michael Barley,`
- `Dear Michelle Renee Grace Steiner,`
- `Dear Russell William John Willson,`

to

- `Dear Bob,`
- `Dear Michelle,`
- `Dear Russell,`

Notice how there are some people with two middle names, which makes things a bit more complicated.

I know that this search syntax

`\r(*{1,})\,`

can be used to find their full name plus the comma at the end and the `r` at the end of `Dear`. But I am not sure what I can use to replace this with so that only the `Dear FirstName,` is left.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you've created a form to generate the 200 letters, wouldn't it be easier to edit the form and re-merge the data?

Comment: Look into the "Mail merge" options of Word. I assume that you have made sure the recipients have accepted (you DID ask, didn't you!?) you sending this kind of send-outs.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure why you believe that you need the backslashes. 
Aside from that, you’re close.

(I assume that you are talking about
Microsoft Word’s “Find and Replace” function, with Wildcards enabled.)

You want to search for

```
(Dear [! ]{1,})*,
```

and replace with

```
\1,
```

I believe that it’s safer to search for “Dear” rather than just “r”;
searching for just “r” can lead to a lot of false positives.

- `[! ]` (i.e., “[!␣]”, where “␣” represents a space)
  means any character other than a space.
- So `[! ]{1,}` means one or more characters
  that are something other than a space. 
  This will match the first name.
- The `*` matches the middle and last names.
- The `,` matches the comma. 
  (As I said, you don’t need backslash.)
- `Dear ⁠` (including the space after it) and `[! ]{1,}` (the first name)
  are enclosed in parentheses, to make them a group.
- Replace with the group (“Dear” + space + first name) and comma.